# Is it bad practice to name a model "Image" in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails 4 application I have a model named `Image`. Image is not a reserved word in Rails 4 as far as I can tell from the list of reserved words listed here:
http://www.rubymagic.org/posts/ruby-and-rails-reserved-words

The problem that I've run into is that the routes for the image class create a helper named `image_path` which happens to already be an assets helper for images. For example, to access the path helper in one of my unit tests I need to call `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.image_path(@image)` which is easy to forget and hard for outsiders to debug.

I'm leaning towards renaming the model to `Photo`, but first wanted to see if anyone had any other solutions.

Comment: Yes.  Don't use Image for the name of your model: http://reservedwords.herokuapp.com/words/image

Comment: @infused, thanks, bookmarking that site, too bad there's not a tag for Rails version.

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem at all naming your model Image, but you will face some issues having a resource controller named `ImagesController` cause then you'll override the URLHelpers `image_path` method.

I think it's not recommended to do that, but you can do if you want to. To solve the routes problem, you can simple give another name to your images controller as below:

```
# config/routes.rb
resource :images, as: :photo # or whatever you want to
```